# Comparing ImageIcons in 2 JButtons

Tags: java

I wonder why am getting null in my comparison that checks if two JButtons have the same ImageIcon? Here is my class

```
public class Card extends JButton{


    // Instance Variables
    private ImageIcon icon;

    private static final int CARD_SIZE = 165;

    public Card(ImageIcon icon){
        setIcon(ResizeIcon(icon));
        this.icon = icon;

        setOpaque(true);
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));

        // Preferred card size
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CARD_SIZE, CARD_SIZE));
    }

    public boolean SameIcon(Card card){
        System.out.println(((ImageIcon)this.getIcon()).getDescription());
        return getIcon() == card.getIcon();
    }

    // Resize the image to fit into JButton regardless of its original dimensions
    private ImageIcon ResizeIcon(ImageIcon imagIcon){
        Image img = imagIcon.getImage(); 
        Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(CARD_SIZE - 5, CARD_SIZE - 5,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  
        return new ImageIcon(newimg);
    }
}
```

My question is basically why i get null when i do (ImageIcon)this.getIcon().getDescription(). It seems like setIcon only sets only ImageIcon and not the Icon. Because it shows on the JButton that an ImageIcon is present but when i try to retrieve it, it get null

Comment: i tried to do a "System.out.println(((ImageIcon)this.getIcon()).getDescription());" in the SameIcon class but all i got was null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to Resize method to return an Image instead so it looked as follows

```
    private Image ResizeIcon(ImageIcon imagIcon){
        return (imagIcon.getImage()).getScaledInstance(
                       CARD_SIZE - 5, 
                       CARD_SIZE - 5,  
                       java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  
    }
```

then when calling the setIcon() Method of any specific JButton, i say

```
setIcon(new ImageIcon(ResizeIcon(icon), icon.toString()));
```

Remember, icon is an ImageIcon variable so its easier to get the location string. I compare the strings instead.

I know its a bit not wise to compare strings, but it proved to be a way out forthe time being